# Does the octave-symbolic package still exist for Ubuntu 22.04/jammy?

Tags: package-management, 22.04, octave

We run a [Jobe server](https://github.com/trampgeek/jobe) for use by our [CodeRunner](https://coderunner.org.nz/) install, including Octave on it. We have previously been asked to include the `octave-symbolic` package as part of our install.

We are now trying to build a new server using Ubuntu 22.04/jammy, but it looks as though [the octave-symbolic package does not exist for this release](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=octave%20symbolic).

As sysadmins, we do not use Octave ourselves. Does anyone know whether the `octave-symbolic` functionality is now included in the main Octave package, in a different Octave package, or whether it is lacking a maintainer (or has had problems making it not possible to release it for Ubuntu 22.04)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the time of Jammy's release, the package was removed from Ubuntu - see [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/octave-symbolic/+bug/1922845) for the package removal - because it was removed in Debian for being a package that failed to build from source (FTBFS).  For the same reasons in Debian, which were replicated and the same problem in Ubuntu, the package was removed.

It was not, it seems, sync blacklisted, but at the time of its removal in Ubuntu, the package had a persistent FTBFS, as documented in Debian Bugs [#982561](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=982561) and [#980707](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=980707).

At the time, the package was not compatible with `sympy` 1.7 which was a dependency, and the package was removed from Testing.  And because of the FTBFS, it was removed from Ubuntu at the time.

It was not fixed in Debian until June 9th, 2022, when version `2.9.1~git.2022.06.09-1` was uploaded to Debian to fix the incompatibilities and have a version update.  By this point, it was long after the Jammy 22.04 release which was in April and is therefore not available in Jammy.

It is, however, in Kinetic now (the next version of Ubuntu, which is not an LTS release).  It is possible this could be backported to Jammy, but that's a task for someone willing to do the work to try and get this into Backports or repackaged into a PPA for Jammy specifically to do.

Comment: Thanks for the very helpful answer! The easiest solution for us is therefore not to update the server from 20.04 to 22.04 this year (we don't _need_ the latest software, but it's nice to be running the latest LTS release when time and practicality allows). We can look at this again in the future, and of course, 24.04 will be out before 22.04 reaches EOL.